# Programming of 'edit text' & 'pushbutton' components of a GUI in MATLAB's GUIDE tool

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a .m file written with definition of input & output variables along with calling of other function files which calculate the numeric output from provided numeric input.

I want to build a GUI in MATLAB for the same.

What I require is coding information for

1)Retrieving numeric data from 'edit text' component & pass this data assigned as input data

2)Set an action by clicking push button to run the program, calculate output from input & display the numeric values as output.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, it's pretty easy. I hope this will be helpful.
1. open guide by typing guide in command window.
2. click blank gui
3. guide window will open
4. click and drag a push button and an edit text.
5. click the editor
6. save your file
7. go to the follwing function

```
  function pushbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

and write down this code below.

```
  str = inputdlg('Enter numbers (seperated by commas)');         
  num = str2num(str{1});    
  a=num(:,1);    
  b=num(:,2);    
  ans=a+b; //or whatever you want to do!    
  caption = sprintf('your answer is %.2f',ans)    
  set(handles.edit,'string',caption)
```

Comment: one thing,you don't need to write code in the edit text function. This is just used for the reference purpose to display your result. You can also use static text box instead.